# c# JsonConverter Attribute with DependencyInjection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, json.net

I'm using JsonConverter to resolve Interfaces in asp core.

Here is my JsonConverter-Impl.

```
 public class InterfaceJsonConverter<T> : Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter
    {
        public InterfaceJsonConverter(Type[] types, ITypeRepository typeRepository=null){
            ...
        }
    }
```

and this is how I call it

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(InterfaceJsonConverter<ISomeInterface>), new object[] {new Type[]{
        typeof(MyCustomType)
    }})]
    public interface ISomeInterface{
    ...
    }
```

Basically this works well when I remove my optional Parameter "typeRepository".
But I Need this Parameter set by an dependencyInjection.

how can I set this?
I already tried to set this Parameter as null in the interface-Attribute like

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(InterfaceJsonConverter<ISomeInterface>), new object[] {new Type[]{
        typeof(MyCustomType)
    },null})]
```

but then I will get an NullReference-Exception.

Is there a way to set null as a constructor-parameter?

Comment: See [Injecting a nullable dependency via constructor requires unity to register that nullable dependency](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41747222/181087)

Comment: thanks but in my case I need to pass this "nullable" in an Attribute where I'm not able to use "new".

Comment: You aren't supposed to use dependency injection with attributes because attributes have no *behavior* and thus have nothing to inject. What you need to do is inject the dependency into the service that does have behavior. See [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28365933/181087) of using filters in MVC. Also read [passive attributes](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/13/passive-attributes/).

Comment: @NightOwl888 Please understand the problem a bit more before being so critical aout it. I admit the question could be clearer, but the problem is the same either way. The attribute doesn't need DI, the resolved converter type does. For instance `[JsonConverter(typeof(MyConverter))]` attributes who's resolved converter needs DI. The `JsonConverterAttribute` itself may not, but `MyConverter`, something that is created by newtonsoft, does.

If OP could new up his own `InterfaceJsonConverter` this wouldn't be an issue. Instantiation is out of OPs control, which means DI is out of his control.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38996344) is the solution you are looking for.

In summary, you must set the `JsonSerializerSettings.ContractResolver` to your own implementation of the `DefaultContractResolver` class, where you override the `CreateObjectContract` method. This method is where you use your dependency injection container to create an instance of the custom converter.